# Implementing custom metric in Google Tag Manager using Javascript

Tags: javascript, macros, google-tag-manager

Our web application contains a series of seven sections. The URL doesn't change throughout these sections so we are using virtual pageviews to track users. The goal of the metric is to find out how many sessions there are in which a user reached the last section (debrief) and triggered an event that falls into one of four categories on a section before reaching the debrief. If a session meets this criteria, I would like the metric to fire '1'. The Javascript function is below.

```
function() {
var obj = document.getElementById("simulation-content"), 
    target = obj.getElementsByClassName('swiper-slide-active')[0],
    attribute = target.getAttribute("data-hash");

return (attribute === "debrief" ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Am I going about this correctly? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Calvin

Comment: it looks alright to me, although your function doesn't have a name, nor is it wrapped in parens (function(){})().

Comment: I'm not sure why the function needs to be wrapped in parens. I have implemented a custom dimension using the same function syntax and it worked fine. When our developer tested the Javascript, he said that it returned the correct value. However, the value is not showing up in GA.

Comment: What's calling the function? And how is it being called?

Comment: This is the expected format for a GTM Macro of the "custom javascript" type and is called by GTM itself (however it will not work if used in a tag - in a custom script tag it would actually need parens to turn it into a self executing function).

Comment: function should be called.

Regarding your implementation, why are you using metrics, while you should implement it as a goal with defined steps - since you have virtual pageviews - you'd get way better data in GA this way - with funnel visualisation etc. Not only table with last step info.